# Где в реестре Windows указывается браузер по умолчанию?

Tags: windows, браузер, реестр

Интересуют все места в реестре, в которых должна быть прописана программа, являющаяся браузером по умолчанию.

С ассоциациями файлов понятно, их перечислять не надо.

Comment: Вам именно про "не является браузером по умолчанию" или про открытие URL'ов?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, мне про запускаемый из других программ браузер.

Comment: Вот KB по теме: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224816

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дефолтный бразузер может быть разным для разных протоколов.

Ассоциации протоколов работают так же, как ассоциации файлов:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
```

где `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` - это результат мержа `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` и `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`.

UP: начиная с висты, ассоциации протоколов пишутся еще и в

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http
```

так что стоит проверять оба варианта.

Длинная статья с подробностями: [How Does Your Browser Know that It’s Not The Default.](https://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/)

Comment: Т. е. надо искать протоколы http и https в этих трёх ветвях?

Comment: @Qwertiy можно искать только в HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. Записывать изменения - в HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: Меня интересует запись. Хочу сделать свою программу дефаултным браузером, чтобы она на основе url выбирала, какой браузер запустить. Ну и ещё несколько действий делала. Кстати, я ещё замечал, что иногда возникает ситуация, что при обычном запуске и запуске из программы с админскими правами (от одного и того же пользователя), запускаются разные браузеры - значит мест должно быть минимум два?

Comment: Кстати, я так понимаю, надо не только `http` менять, но и `https`.

Comment: _начиная с висты, ассоциации протоколов пишутся еще и в_
 что-то ничего туда не пишется, в семёрке по крайней мере. Или не понятно как это можно менять, т.к. там hash и progid только

Answer (score 0):

Включи RegMon, запусти какой нить Chrome и сделай ему set default browser и смотри результат.

Comment: RegMon на современных версиях винды не запускается

Comment: Filemon and Regmon are combined now into much more powerful Procmon, which works well on Windows 7 x64 or higher.